# function undefined on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form which should submit via ajax when the submit button is clicked but I get function undefined. The form is in a div which gets loaded into the main page so I have put the  tags under the form to make sure that the form is loaded before the script. Having read some other solutions I have tried adding window.NewSearchFunction instead of NewsearchFuntion but it still doesnt work.

My form:

```
<form class="inline" name="Form1">
    <input class="inline" name="employeeid" id="employeeid" type="hidden" size="30" autofocus value="<?php echo $employee[$k]["employeeid"]; ?>" />

    //More Fields Here

    <p class="inline">
        <label class="inline" for="pensioncompany">Company Pension:</label>
        <input class="inline" type="text" id="pensioncompany" name="pensioncompany" size="30" value="<?php echo $employee[$k]["pensioncompany"]; ?>" />
    </p>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" onclick="NewSearchFunction(e)" value="Update Details">
    </td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
</form>
<script src="editemployeedetailsajax.js"></script>
```

editemployeedetailsajax.js:

```
// JavaScript Document
var NewSearchFunction;
$(document).ready(function(){
    var window.NewSearchFunction;

    NewSearchFunction(e) = function() {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log()
        var employeeid=document.getElementById("employeeid").value;
        var firstname=document.getElementById("firstname").value;
        var surname=document.getElementById("lastname").value;
        var addr1=document.getElementById("addr1").value;
        var addr2=document.getElementById("addr2").value;
        var town=document.getElementById("town").value;
        var county=document.getElementById("county").value;
        var postcode=document.getElementById("postcode").value;
        var tel1=document.getElementById("tel1").value;
        var work=document.getElementById("work").value;
        var mobile=document.getElementById("mobile").value;
        var sex=document.getElementById("sex").value;
        var DOB=document.getElementById("DOB").value;
        var ninumber=document.getElementById("ninumber").value;
        var payrollnumber=document.getElementById("payrollnumber").value;
        var sortcode=document.getElementById("sortcode").value;
        var accountnumber=document.getElementById("accountnumber").value;
        var annualleaveentitlement=document.getElementById("annualleaveentitlement").value;
        var vehicleid=document.getElementById("vehicleid").value;
        var fuelcardid=document.getElementById("fuelcardid").value;
        var mobileid=document.getElementById("mobileid").value;
        var pensionindividual=document.getElementById("pensionindividual").value;
        var pensioncompany=document.getElementById("pensioncompany").value;

        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.

        var dataString = 'employeeid=' + employeeid + '&firstname=' + firstname + '&surname=' + lastname + '&addr1=' + addr1 + '&addr2=' + addr2 + '&town=' + town + '&county=' + county + '&postcode=' + postcode + '&tel1=' + tel1 + '&work=' + work + '&mobile=' + mobile + '&sex=' + sex + '&DOB=' + DOB + '&ninumber=' + ninumber + '&payrollnumber=' + payrollnumber + '&sortcode=' + sortcode + '&accountnumber=' + accountnumber + '&annualleaveentitlement=' + annualleaveentitlement + '&vehicleid=' + vehicleid + '&fuelcardid=' + fuelcardid + '&mobileid=' + mobileid + '&pensionindividual=' + pensionindividual + '&pensioncompany=' + pensioncompany;

        // AJAX code to submit form.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submit.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                alert(html);
            });
        );
```

Comment: Move the function outside of `ready()`. OR use jquery to handle event, _better_?

Comment: That has stopped the notdefined problem but now everything that should be submitted is just going into the address bar and refreshing the page rather than posting to submit.php

Comment: Change from `type = submit` to `type = button`

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you may want to have a look at [jQuery's `serialize` function](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: You also appear to be missing a bunch of `}` brackets

Answer (score 0):

Like Tushar pointed, your NewSearchFunction(e) is defined only after the DOM is loaded, but when DOM is loaded, in the input element you have a reference to the NewSearchFunction which is not defined at the moment.

Better approach is indeed to use jquery element binding:

```
$('input#submit').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault()
    console.log()
    var employeeid=document.getElementById("employeeid").value;
    var firstname=document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var surname=document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    var addr1=document.getElementById("addr1").value;
    var addr2=document.getElementById("addr2").value;
    var town=document.getElementById("town").value;
    var county=document.getElementById("county").value;
    var postcode=document.getElementById("postcode").value;
    var tel1=document.getElementById("tel1").value;
    var work=document.getElementById("work").value;
    var mobile=document.getElementById("mobile").value;
    var sex=document.getElementById("sex").value;
    var DOB=document.getElementById("DOB").value;
    var ninumber=document.getElementById("ninumber").value;
    var payrollnumber=document.getElementById("payrollnumber").value;
    var sortcode=document.getElementById("sortcode").value;
    var accountnumber=document.getElementById("accountnumber").value;
    var annualleaveentitlement=document.getElementById("annualleaveentitlement").value;
    var vehicleid=document.getElementById("vehicleid").value;
    var fuelcardid=document.getElementById("fuelcardid").value;
    var mobileid=document.getElementById("mobileid").value;
    var pensionindividual=document.getElementById("pensionindividual").value;
    var pensioncompany=document.getElementById("pensioncompany").value;

    // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.

    var dataString = 'employeeid=' + employeeid + '&firstname=' + firstname + '&surname=' + lastname + '&addr1=' + addr1 + '&addr2=' + addr2 + '&town=' + town + '&county=' + county + '&postcode=' + postcode + '&tel1=' + tel1 + '&work=' + work + '&mobile=' + mobile + '&sex=' + sex + '&DOB=' + DOB + '&ninumber=' + ninumber + '&payrollnumber=' + payrollnumber + '&sortcode=' + sortcode + '&accountnumber=' + accountnumber + '&annualleaveentitlement=' + annualleaveentitlement + '&vehicleid=' + vehicleid + '&fuelcardid=' + fuelcardid + '&mobileid=' + mobileid + '&pensionindividual=' + pensionindividual + '&pensioncompany=' + pensioncompany;

    // AJAX code to submit form.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            alert(html);
        });
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing an `onclick` attribute on the button or registering a click-event handler on the button, you can leave the button with `type="submit"`, and then register a submit-event handler on the form. You just have to call `event.preventDefault()` inside the submit-event handler to prevent the normal form submission, and of course, you should register the event handler inside a document-ready handler.

Relevant HTML:

```
<script src="editemployeedetailsajax.js"></script>
<form name="Form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="employeeid" value="..." />
    <input type="text" name="pensioncompany" value="..." />
    <input type="submit" value="Update Details" />
</form>
```

editemployeedetailsajax.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form[name=Form1]').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submit.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
               alert(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
```